# What is the difference between TF model garden and tf.keras.applications?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

With the new TensorFlow 2 we have their [Model Garden](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official) (in GitHub under `/models`), as well as the pre-trained models for Keras under `tf.keras.applications`.

What is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Tensorflow Keras Applications***
-  pre-trained models for CNNs. They include most frequently used CNN architectures such as ResNet, InceptionNet, VGG etc. 
- tf.keras.applications allow you to directly import a CNN architecture (see docs https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications?hl=en) customize its loss and use it as you like.

***Tensorflow Model Garden*** 
-  models for other tasks such as NLP, object detection etc. These models are too maintained by TensorFlow. 
- tf model garden are not part of tf core API so you can't import them directly as you do for tf.applications.